# scroll based on dragenter event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to scroll up step by step and scroll down step by step using jquery. (jquery ui not appreciated).
i have a 2 divs

```
    <div class="upper" style="height:35px;background-color:red;right:0;left:0;top:0;position:fixed;width:100%;z-index:2000"></div>
    <div class="lower" style="height:35px;background-color:red;right:0;left:0;bottom:0;position:fixed;width:100%;z-index:2000"></div>
```

if i drag an image and hover on first div (upper),it should scroll up step by stell.
if i drag and hover on 2nd div it should scroll down manually.

in both cases scrolling should stop if i came out of the div.

i am trying to implement it using events

```
var isleftDragPosition=true;;
            $('.upper').on('dragleave', function(){
                console.log("hidragleave");
                var isleftDragPosition=true;
            });
            $('.lower').on('dragleave', function(){
                console.log("hi2dragleave")
                var isleftDragPosition=true;
            });
            $('.upper').on('dragenter', function(){
                var isleftDragPosition=false;
                while(!isleftDragPosition){
                    var x=document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                    console.log("to upper position",x);
                    window.scrollTo(0, x-2);
                }
            });
            $('.lower').on('dragenter', function(){
                console.log("hi2dragenter",document.documentElement.scrollTop)
                window.scrollTo(1000, 1000);
            });
```

i am trying it with the top div to scroll up, but the code crashes my tab(hang).

how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining your flag in each handler, so the change is not saved. Also, while loop might be to fast for your particular case. I modified code like this:

```
$('.upper').on('dragenter', function(){
    isleftDragPosition=false;
    clearInterval(interval);
    var f = function() {
      if(!isleftDragPosition){
          var x=document.documentElement.scrollTop;
          console.log("to upper position",x);
          window.scrollTo(0, x-2);
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }
    setInterval(f, 1000);
});
```

Hope this helps.